# Delete an item from array using index sent from front end

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to delete an item from a php array.

I have a json file that I am using to store data. The json file looks like the following.

```
{
    "1.49514754373E+12": {
        "description": "I don't like it",
        "fileNames": [
            "a.jpg",
            "b.jpg",
            "c.jpg"
        ]
    },
    "1.4952754451E+12": {
        "description": "hey there",
        "fileNames": [
            "a.jpg"
        ]
    }
}
```

My php code looks like this

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')  {

  //the id is sent from the front end. In this case it is '0';
  $data =  $_REQUEST['id'];

  $index = json_decode($data);

  // get json from file
  $json = file_get_contents('test.json');

  // turn json into array
  $masterArr = json_decode($json, true);

  unset($masterArr[$index]);

  // turn array back to json
  $json = json_encode($masterArr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

  // save json to file
  file_put_contents('test.json', $json);

  echo $json;

?>
```

I have tried to use `unset` - `unset($masterArr[$index]);` but this doesn't work. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

When I `echo $index` I get `0`;

and `var_dump(masterArr)` gives me

```
array(2) {
  ["1.49514754373E+12"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["description"]=>
    string(15) "I don't like it"
    ["fileNames"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "a.jpg"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "b.jpg"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "c.jpg"
    }
  }
  ["1.4952754451E+12"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["description"]=>
    string(17) "hey there"
    ["fileNames"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "a.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

In the example above I am trying to remove

```
"1.49514754373E+12": {
    "description": "I don't like it",
    "fileNames": [
        "a.jpg",
        "b.jpg",
        "c.jpg"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Output values of `$masterArr` and `$index` and see if you have this key in your array.

Comment: befor you save $json to file, show it's content

Comment: show $masterArr and $index here

Comment: Please modularize your code. I recommend a class that purely deals with the getting & saving of data with your file. Also a function that is passed an index to the Data that deletes it. another Function that spits out complete data set. In another class you may want to validate your data that is received. I recommend phpunit to unit test all these features. #ftw

Comment: why you doing `$index = json_decode($data);` this ? Is it `json` too ?

Comment: there is no index 0 in the outer array, which elemet you want to unset?

Comment: Now try to see `$masterArr[$index]`, its clear that there is no data at index `0`.

Comment: @peterflanagan if this, you need to `unset($masterArr["1.49514754373E+12"])` not `unset($masterArr[0])`

Comment: ok, what is the best way to get `"1.49514754373E+12"` in my php file bearing in mind I am sending an index from the front end

Comment: For that your `$_REQUEST['id']` should be same

Comment: @KrisRoofe got it!

Answer (score 0):

unset() destroys the specified variables. if you want to remove file than use unlink function of php

Answer (score 0):

To unset any variable use the delete statement:

```
delete favorites.favorites[1].items[1]
```

If you want to actually remove an item from the array so that all items after it in the array move down to lower indexes, you would use something like this:

```
favorites.favorites[1].items.splice(1, 1);
```

For  `.splice()`, you pass the index where you want to start modifying the array and then the number of items to remove this `.splice(1, 1)` which will remove 1 item starting at index 1.

Answer (score -1):

As per i see comment, you want to remove all content if `$index` is `0`.

so just do as below

```
$data =  $_REQUEST['id'];

$index = json_decode($data);
if($index == 0){
  file_put_contents('test.json', "");
  // you can also return your proper response here.
  return;
 }
```

Comment: this needs to be dynamic. what if there is more than one item in the object

Comment: This handle only case for `0`